# Cortar uma imagem e exibir as duas partes que foram cortadas

Tags: c#

Estou iniciando na programação e me surgiu uma dúvida. Estou tentando cortar uma imagem ao meio e mostrar em dois picture box os dois cortes.

[image: Imagem Original]

Estou fazendo o corte da seguinte forma.

```
private void Btn_Recortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Lobj_ImagemcortadaEsquerda = RecortarImagem(ImagemOriginalCopiada, 0, 0, 100, 60);
Lobj_ImagemCortadaDireita = RecortarImagem(ImagemOriginalCopiada, 0, 0, 200, 60);

pictureBox1.Image = Lobj_ImagemCortadaDireita;
pictureBox2.Image = Lobj_ImagemcortadaEsquerda;

pictureBox1.Image = Lobj_Imagemcortada2;
pictureBox2.Image = Lobj_Imagemcortada;
}
```

Método que recorta

```
public Bitmap RecortarImagem(Bitmap ImagemOriginal, int cropX, int cropY, int cropWidth, int cropHeight)
{
ImagemRecortada = true;

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
Bitmap cropped = ImagemOriginalCopiada.Clone(rect, ImagemOriginal.PixelFormat);
return cropped; 
}
```

A ideia é ter duas imagens. No primeiro pictureBox:

[image: PictureBox1]

e o segundo pictureBox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá para obter o tamanho original antes de fazer o corte.

```
int width = ImagemOriginalCopiada.Size.Width;
int height = ImagemOriginalCopiada.Size.Height;
Lobj_ImagemcortadaEsquerda = RecortarImagem(ImagemOriginalCopiada, 0, 0, width/2, height);
Lobj_ImagemCortadaDireita = RecortarImagem(ImagemOriginalCopiada, width / 2, 0, width/2, height);

pictureBox1.Image = Lobj_ImagemcortadaEsquerda;
pictureBox2.Image = Lobj_ImagemCortadaDireita;
```